# Attempting to add list to dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a file (row_data.csv) I'm reading in that is in the following comma separated syntax:

```
Title1,https://url1|https://url2
```

The file has two fields. The one requiring the attention is field 2, and I'm creating a list out of the two elements which are delimited by the '|' character with this code:

```
f = open("row_data.csv")
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    desktop_images_link = row[1]
    desktop_images = desktop_images_link.split('|')
    for x in desktop_images:
        myitem["Item"]["PictureDetails"]["PictureURL"][0].append(x)
```

I've been unsuccessful in migrating this list into the below dictionary:

```
  myitem = {
            "Item": {
                "Title": "{}".format(item_title),
                "PictureDetails": {
                    "GalleryType": "Gallery",
                    "PictureURL": []
```

I've tried modifying the dictionary to just look like "PictureURL": [] and that doesn't work.

I've also tried tinkering with the syntax in my for loop where I'm appending the values of the list, but I can not get this to work.

All assistance is MORE than appreciated.

The output that the JSON should represent is as follows:

```
"PictureURL": [
    "https://url1",
    "https://url2"
]
```

Comment: I've added those details to end of my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First you need to initialize myitem and set PictureURL as empty list. then you can append url to that list**

```
f = open("data/row_data.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    desktop_images_link = row[1]
    desktop_images = desktop_images_link.split('|')

    myitem = {
        "Item": {
            "Title": "{}".format(row[0]),
            "PictureDetails": {
                "GalleryType": "Gallery",
                "PictureURL": []
            }
        }
    }

    for x in desktop_images:
        myitem["Item"]["PictureDetails"]["PictureURL"].append(x)

    print(myitem)
```

Comment: Looks like I needed to get rid of the [] after ["PictureURL"] -- thank you sir.

Comment: @user3299633 Yes. This `myitem["Item"]["PictureDetails"]["PictureURL"][0].append(x)` should changed to myitem["Item"]["PictureDetails"]["PictureURL"].append(x)

Answer (score 2):

If `PictureURL` is initialized to `[]` inside the dictionary while creating the dictionary `myItem`, then your below statement:

```
myitem["Item"]["PictureDetails"]["PictureURL"][0].append(x)
```

should be

```
myitem["Item"]["PictureDetails"]["PictureURL"].append(x)
```

If you `PictureURL` is a list, just append to the list, `[0]` will try to append to the first element of the list which is not what you want.

You can also use list comprehension and do it like below:

```
f = open("row_data.csv")
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    desktop_images_link = row[1]
    desktop_images = desktop_images_link.split('|')
    myitem["Item"]["PictureDetails"]["PictureURL"].extend([x for x in desktop_images])
```